# Select all forms with no records in the last 24 hours (but some records in the last 48, etc)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (in an Oracle DB) that has

- A form name ('name')
- A creation date ('gmts')
- Other columns (I don't care)

I can get a count for the last 24 hours by

```
select name, count(name) from table where gmts > sysdate -1 group by name;
```

(I'm leaving out ordering for simplicity) Similarly, I can do this for any time by playing with the date field.

What I'd like to do is show all the forms that had zero entries in the last 24 hours, but 1+ in the last 48 (as this could indicate a problem with flow, but won't flag obsolete forms).

Comment: Dbms? (SYSDATE is product specific.)

Comment: Oracle, should have specified...sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Oracle then:

```
select name, count(name) 
    from table 
where gmts > sysdate -1 
    or name = (select name from table where gmts > sysdate -2 and rownum <= 1) 
group by name
order by gmts desc;
```

If it is MySQL use Limit instead:

```
select name, count(name) 
    from table 
where gmts > sysdate -1 
    or name = (select name from table where gmts > sysdate -2 order by gmts desc LIMIT 1) 
group by name;
```

Comment: I've tried many variations of the Oracle version, but it always says missing right parenthesis, even though I can see it's balanced.. Something weird (ORA-00907), but this looks like it should work.

Comment: @TaoOfGaming I've updated the Oracle query if you want to try that again?

Comment: This runs but shows things that had forms in the last 24 hours. I want forms that have no entries in the last 24 hours, but some in the 24 before that.

Comment: @TaoOfGaming you need to add another where filter for that but I don't know your tables enough to say what that is i.e. I don't know what data would represent a form with no entry? For example If it was when name is null then simply add "And name is null" to the where clause

Answer (score 0):

With some searching, I found

```
select distinct name from table 
  where gmts > systdate - 2 AND
  name NOT IN 
     (select distinct scan_type_nm from document where gmts > sysdate -1)
  order by name asc;
```